# Selecting counts of a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, count, substring

I know this has to be an easy select but I am having no luck figuring it out. I've got a table has a field of customer grouping codes and I'm trying to get a count of each distinct character 2 through 6 sets. In my past foxpro experience a simple

`select distinct substr(custcode,2,5), count (*) from a group by 1`

would work, but this doesn't appear to work in sql server queries. The error message indicated it didn't like using the number reference in the group by so I changed it to custcode but the count just returns 1 for each, as I assume the count is after the distinct occurs so there is only one. If I change the count to `count(distinct substring(custcode,2,5))` and remove the first distinct substring I just get a count of how many different codes exist. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `count(distinct substring(custcode,2,5)), substring(custcode,2,5)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are redundant, you just want `GROUP BY`, and you want to `GROUP BY` the same thing you are selecting:

```
select substr(custcode,2,5), count (*) 
from a 
group by substr(custcode,2,5)
```

In SQL Server you can use column aliases/numbers in the `ORDER BY` clause, but not in `GROUP BY`.

Ie. `ORDER BY 1` will order by the first selected column, but many consider it bad practice to use column indexes, using aliases/column names is clearer.

Comment: I removed "indexes" because that is completely ambiguous. Please use another term like ordinal position.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Do you think "ordinal position" is more commonly understood than "column index"?  I'm open to wording changes, but it's clear that the OP was attempting to use the column index in the grouping.  Maybe just "column numbers"?

Comment: Yes, I do. "Column numbers" is much better than "column indexes" but I'm fairly certain that "ordinal position" is unambiguous.